# How to convert imperial to metric units?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math, units-of-measurement

This is more of a general question of both code and math. I'm not at all good at math, and I'm still learning how to apply math in programming.

Let's say, I have an object of data that has the amount, the measurement, and the type, such as `feet` or `lb`.

```
const data = {
  0: {
    'type': 'imperial',
    'unit': 'ft',
    'amount': 3 
  },
  1: {
    'type': 'imperial',
    'unit': 'lb',
    'amount': 5
  },
  2: {
    'type': 'imperial',
    'unit': 'mph',
    'amount': 7 
  }
}
```

And I need to go through this data and convert each according to the type (assuming type is what it's called)

```
Object.keys(data).map(key => {
    convert(data[key]['amount'], data[key]['type'], data[key]['unit'])
})
```

And the function converts this:

```
const convert = (amount, type, unit) => {
   const calc = // ???
   return calc;
}
```

My question is, how do I convert depending on the type of measurement? I know that 1 foot is 0.3048 meters, and if I needed to convert 5 feet to meters, I'd do `5*0.3048`.

However, how can I apply this in code, with a list of imperial and metric units and how would I add this to the convert function?

Comment: As a first step, you could do `if (type == "imperial") { ... }` and in there `if (unit == "feet") return amount * 0.3048;`

Comment: Maybe you need to know which unit to convert into as well, for example mph becomes m/s or km/h?

Comment: Yes, I can understand how to convert with something like https://www.mathsisfun.com/metric-imperial-conversion-charts.html just not sure how to apply it in code...

Comment: @ChrisG I probably need to do this for about 10 measurements. How would this look if the units were stored in it's own object and I'd go through each one?

I also need to convert from metric to imperial as well via click event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `converter` Object with functions to convert and labels to display, here's an example ( adjust the values and units to your needs ) :

```js
const data = {
  0: {
    type: "imperial",
    unit: "ft",
    amount: 3
  },
  1: {
    type: "imperial",
    unit: "lb",
    amount: 5
  },
  2: {
    type: "imperial",
    unit: "mph",
    amount: 7
  }
};

const converter = {
  imperialToMetric: {
    ft: val => val * 0.3048,
    lb: val => val * 0.453592,
    mph: val => val * 1.60934,
    labels: {
      ft: "meters",
      lb: "Kg",
      mph: "kmh"
    }
  },
  metric: {
    // reverse the above
  }
};

const result = Object.values(data).map(({ amount, type, unit }) => ({
  amount: converter.imperialToMetric[unit](amount),
  unit: converter.imperialToMetric.labels[unit],
  type: "metric"
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: When you say reverse, do you mean divide instead of multiply?

Comment: How would I convert _only once_ of an object and store it? Not really related to the question but I'm curious how I'd do it in this case.

Comment: not necessarily, you can check the table of conversion ( but doing a quick match, yes you can divide instead of multiply ) , to convert only once, you can do `const result = {
  amount: converter.imperialToMetric[data[0].unit](data[0].amount),
  unit: converter.imperialToMetric.labels[data[0].unit],
  typ: "metric"
};`